# Unable to update Azure Network Security Group using az cli

Tags: azure, powershell

I am attempting to update a Network Security Group (SourceAddressPrefixes) via the cli. To begin, it appears that the az cmdlet `Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig` is broke; the output from the command states that it's succeeded but no change actually occurs to the NSG. Others have complained about this but no fix from MSFT yet.

With that said, I have tried a workaround method which saves the NSG in a variable, sets the `SourceAddressPrefixes`, and updates the NSG after:

```
$SaContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $SAName).Context
$table = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $TableName -Context $SaContext).CloudTable
$IPs = (Get-AzTableRow -Table $table).IP
$IPs = '"{0}"' -f ($IPs -join '","') # Updates the IPs to be double-quoted and separated by commas


$NSG = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $MyResourceGroup -Name $NSGName
($nsg.SecurityRules | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'HTTPS'}).SourceAddressPrefix = $IPList
$NSG | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup | Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $RuleName | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The issue with the code above is that the cmdlet `Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup` will not except value type `system.string`. It will only accept `System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]`. Due to that I perform the following:

```
$IPList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$IPList.Add($IPs)
```

Now, the previous `Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup` accepts the array but now the command fails because the array values aren't double-quoted with  a comma to separate them. Not sure what to do at this point.

Actual error messages below:

`Cannot convert the (ip addresses here) value of type [system.string] to type "Systems.Collections.Generic.IList[System.String]`

And once I convert my variable(array) to match that requirement the error is:
`nsgRule has invalid Address Prefix. Value Provided (ip addresses here) statuscode:400` which i'm sure is because converting the array removes the double-quotes & commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the Source Address Prefix of one Network Security Group rule, its value should be like

```
192.162.0.1
192.162.1.1
...
```

For example

```
$nsg= Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name  $NSGName -ResourceGroupName $MyResourceGroup

$IPList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$IPList.Add("192.162.0.1")
$IPList.Add("192.162.1.1")

($nsg.SecurityRules | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Port_8080'}).SourceAddressPrefix =$IPList

$nsg|Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup |  Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "Port_8080" | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

[image]

Comment: That's adding the IPs one by one; i'm pulling the values from Azure table storage that automatically puts it in string format and it's over 200 IPs.

Comment: Once I added a `foreach` statement to pull all of my IPs into the array it worked. Thanks again